# Access ingress IP from a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have got an authentication service. This service is behind an ingress (GKE in my case) for external API calls. When the signup function of the authentication service is called, it will send an email for email verification purpose. The link in this email has to point to the IP of ingress. In order to achieve that, my authentication service has to know the IP of the ingress. How can this be configured dynamically in k8s without storing the ingress IP[ address in a config file?

Many thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Have you considered using the static ip address in GKE (with this the ip is known in advance)?. In addition to use static IP with domain name you should update your dns records with address type record to point to your reserved static ip. This will allow you to use nslookup to find the ip address for this specific host without adding to the service account associated with your pod additional permissions.

Comment: Can you also provide more information about your config (ingress controller, more insight about that auth service etc) ?

Comment: thanks @thomas; I thought of that approach. it make sense to me. I'll go with that for now

Comment: Great! I'll place short answer soon for better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by default GKE allocates [ephemeral external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress) the simplest solution is to reserve [static ip address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#reservedaddress). This can be done with new one or you can promote existing ephemeral IP to static one. With this solution the IP address is known in advance but the drawback of that the IP would have to be hardcoded into the application.

To avoid hardcoding this you could use nslookup to find ip address for this specific host. With this you should update your dns records with an address type record to point to you reserved static IP address.  Please refer to your DNS service`s documentation on setting DNS A records to [configure your domain name](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#configuring_your_domain_name_records).

For more reading check [how to configure static ip address](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#optional_configuring_a_static_ip_address).

---

The alternative way would be also to  [access the Kubernetes REST API directly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api) and fetch the IP address from there.  This depending on your architecture and application design will required appropriate authentication towards API.